# Longtable in landscape format

Tags: longtable, landscape, books

I am writing my PhD thesis and I have the following problem:

I use

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
```

In Appendix, I need to switch to the landscape mode and add some figures in the first part of the Appendix. Later, I need to add more longtables which are wider than the allowed text width. Thus after putting the figures I use

```
\pagestyle{empty}
```

However, it is not enough and thus I would like to make the allowed text width wider, i.e. to center the longtables over the whole page width.

How can I switch off all margins in the landscape mode. I tried the geometry package with the `\newgeometry` command, however, this solution seems not to work in the landscape mode.

Working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
        \section{Section 4}
            \setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\textheight}    
            \begin{landscape}
                Some text

                \newpage

                \pagestyle{empty}

                \begin{center}
                    \begin{longtable}{l||rrr|rrr|rrr|rrr|rrr}
                            {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X}\\
                            \hline\hline
                        \endfirsthead
                            {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X} & {\bf X}\\
                            \hline\hline
                        \endhead
                        \endfoot
                        \endlastfoot
                        XXXXXXXXXX
                            & XXX
                                & XXX
                                    & XXX
                                        & XXX
                                            & XXX
                                                & XXX
                                                    & XXX
                                                        & XXX
                                                            & XXX
                                                                & XXX
                                                                    & XXX
                                                                        & XXX
                                                                            & XXX
                                                                                & XXX
                                                                                    & XXX\\
                    \end{longtable}
                \end{center}
            \end{landscape}

        \section{A next section}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for all answers.

Best regards,
T.

Comment: I've never tried `\newgeometry` in landscape mode but I think you've to switch the width/heights then. But a working, compilable document would be far more helpful. In my point of view, screwing up the margins is a bad idea. Try to improve the tables instead

Comment: If you post an example of these tables (not the whole table), maybe we can help you fix it. Anyway, the geometry command goes as follows: `Content A ... \newgeometry{<new margins>} exception content ... \restoregeometry ... continue content A`. But I agree with Christian that it'd be better to fix the tables.

Comment: @Alenanno: The general problem with `\newgeometry` -- it issues a new page (but this is perhaps required anyway here)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think that, even without mentioning the fact that it's still extra code, I don't like the idea (as a reader) to rotate the document I'm reading because the table has another orientation. I'd rather re-do the table from scratch to fit in a page in portrait mode. That's why, especially in this case, I agree with you about the table.

Comment: @Alenanno: I've not done landscape tables for ages and in my master or later on the PhD thesis there were no landscape tables -- I agree with you -- landscape mode isn't the best idea

Comment: Please don't use `\bf` -- that's outdated. Use `\bfseries` -- it's ok in a table cell or provide special table column type for this

Comment: My preference would go to typesetting the big table as a separate document, in landscape format, with the desired margins and then using `pdfpages` and `\includepdf`.